# Are there any sites that have mysql databases to download?

Tags: mysql

I occasionally do some mysql development.  Is there a repository somewhere where people have posted their mysql database layouts?  Something similar maybe to this: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1939530#
I found this for an ecommerse app I am creating, but it would be nice if there was a site that had a lot more where you could just cut and paste and tweak to create tables.  Also, what is the proper term for a mysql database definition?  Schema?

Comment: Original, I'll give you that.

Comment: Could you give this link a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609/any-sample-mysql-databases-i-can-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything like you're asking for, but mostly because with tools like Chive and phpMyAdmin it's very easy to create a database visually.

Comment: I agree it is easy to create databases, I was mostly thinking of it as a development tool for ideas.  Thanks for the comment though.